# Im having error regarding the timezone in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im having this error:

```
date_create(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
```

so I modified my config.php
from:

```
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
```

to:

```
$config['time_reference'] = 'gmt';
```

after modifying, I got this error:

```
Message: mktime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.
```

I tried this on my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

that may work but I want to modify the config.php so I shouldn't include `date_default_timezone_set()` all the time in my code.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how to solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

in your config.php

Comment: where he mentioned that ??? he tried this in the other php files not in config file

Comment: yeaaaa it is okkk ..  :)

Comment: Thanks both for the quick response and big help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Place this code within your config file.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT');
```

or

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Comment: 'Etc/GMT'  <- what's this? how it differs from 'America/New_York'?

Comment: Current date and time according to `America/New_York` will be Wed `11-Mar-2015 01:48 A.M.` while according to `Etc/GMT` it will be `11:18:29 AM on Wednesday, Mar 11, 2015` you can google it for difference or refer this link's [link 1](http://www.prokerala.com/travel/timezones/Etc/GMT) and [link 2](http://timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo.tzc?s=default&tz=America/New_York)

Comment: `function index() { 
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $this->loadview();
    }`

I tried the above code but still throws me an error. I dont want to modify my php.ini because I might misconfigure something because other programmers also use it.

Comment: Just place the code `date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT');`  before `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Answer (score 0):

What if you check your `php.ini` file and look for this particular part: `date.timezone`

**php.ini**

```
 [Date]
 ; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
 ; http://php.net/date.timezone
 date.timezone=Europe/Berlin
```

Define your desired timezone at `date.timezone`. If this line does not exists on your php.ini, just create one and define your desired timezone.

If you want you have your own global timezone set on CI, I usually put it on the top of `index.php` on your app root directory.